# numbers fading behind the display in JS calculator

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to code a simple tiny calculator. It's working fine, but the input numbers keep filling out the display even after if it's filled. I want it to stop receiving inputs once the display is full.

Please review the code if you don't get what I mean.

```js
// defining variables for buttons
const digit0 = document.getElementById("digit0");
digit0.addEventListener("click", input);
const digit1 = document.getElementById("digit1");
digit1.addEventListener("click", input);
const digit2 = document.getElementById("digit2");
digit2.addEventListener("click", input);
const digit3 = document.getElementById("digit3");
digit3.addEventListener("click", input);
const digit4 = document.getElementById("digit4");
digit4.addEventListener("click", input);
const digit5 = document.getElementById("digit5");
digit5.addEventListener("click", input);
const digit6 = document.getElementById("digit6");
digit6.addEventListener("click", input);
const digit7 = document.getElementById("digit7");
digit7.addEventListener("click", input);
const digit8 = document.getElementById("digit8");
digit8.addEventListener("click", input);
const digit9 = document.getElementById("digit9");
digit9.addEventListener("click", input);
const digitPlus = document.getElementById("digitPlus");
digitPlus.addEventListener("click", input);
const digitMinus = document.getElementById("digitMinus");
digitMinus.addEventListener("click", input);
const digitMultiply = document.getElementById("digitMultiply");
digitMultiply.addEventListener("click", input);
const digitDivision = document.getElementById("digitDivision");
digitDivision.addEventListener("click", input);
const decimalBtn = document.getElementById("decimalBtn");
decimalBtn.addEventListener("click", input);

//Numpad and Keyboard events
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.code === "NumpadEnter" || e.code === "Enter") {
    calculate();
  } else if (e.code === "Backspace") {
    del();
  } else if (e.code === "Delete") {
    reset();
  } else {
    input(e);
  }
});

//Variables for executing calculation(equal button) and clearing the results
const digitEquals = document.getElementById("digitEquals");
digitEquals.addEventListener("click", calculate);
const resetBtn = document.getElementById("resetBtn");
resetBtn.addEventListener("click", reset);
const clearBtn = document.getElementById("clearBtn");
clearBtn.addEventListener("click", del);
const display = document.getElementById("display");
let displayCurrentResult = "";

//input function for activating the buttons
function input(e) {
  let inputValue = "";

  if (e.type === "click") {
    inputValue = e.target.innerText;
  } else {
    if (e.key === "0") {
      inputValue = "0";
    } else if (e.key === "1") {
      inputValue = "1";
    } else if (e.key === "2") {
      inputValue = "2";
    } else if (e.key === "3") {
      inputValue = "3";
    } else if (e.key === "4") {
      inputValue = "4";
    } else if (e.key === "5") {
      inputValue = "5";
    } else if (e.key === "6") {
      inputValue = "6";
    } else if (e.key === "7") {
      inputValue = "7";
    } else if (e.key === "8") {
      inputValue = "8";
    } else if (e.key === "9") {
      inputValue = "9";
    } else if (e.key === "+") {
      inputValue = "+";
    } else if (e.key === "-") {
      inputValue = "-";
    } else if (e.key === "*") {
      inputValue = "*";
    } else if (e.key === "/") {
      inputValue = "/";
    } else if (e.key === "=") {
      inputValue = "=";
    } else if (e.key === ".") {
      inputValue = ".";
    }
  }
  if (
    (displayCurrentResult.substring(-1) === "*" ||
      displayCurrentResult.substring(-1) === "/" ||
      displayCurrentResult.substring(-1) === "-" ||
      displayCurrentResult.substring(-1) === "+") &&
    (inputValue === "*" ||
      inputValue === "/" ||
      inputValue === "-" ||
      inputValue === "+")
  ) {
    displayCurrentResult = displayCurrentResult.slice(0, -1) + inputValue;
  } else {
    displayCurrentResult += inputValue;
  }
  display.innerText = commaSeparator(displayCurrentResult);
}

function calculate() {
  display.innerText = commaSeparator(eval(displayCurrentResult));
  displayCurrentResult = eval(displayCurrentResult).toString();
}

function reset() {
  displayCurrentResult = "";
  display.innerText = commaSeparator(displayCurrentResult);
}

function del() {
  displayCurrentResult = displayCurrentResult.substring(
    0,
    displayCurrentResult.length - 1
  );
  display.innerText = commaSeparator(displayCurrentResult);
}

function commaSeparator(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(#154b25, #4747ee) no-repeat fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}

.calc-wrapper {
  width: 15rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#display {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: center;
  border: 5px solid #ee5858;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  height: 3.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #0de831;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  background: #525151;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #0e0202;
}

.keys {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  border: 1px solid #e12727;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(#346a9f, #6b310f);
  padding-top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px;
}

.digit {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #826ee0;
}

.digit:hover {
  background-color: #63b8c2;
  color: white;
}

.digit:active {
  background-color: #0de831;
}

.clear:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.ac:hover {
  background-color: orangered;
}
```

```html
<div class="calc-wrapper">
  <div id="display"></div>
  <div class="keys">
    <div class="digit 1" id="digit1">1</div>
    <div class="digit 2" id="digit2">2</div>
    <div class="digit 3" id="digit3">3</div>
    <div class="digit 4" id="digit4">4</div>
    <div class="digit 5" id="digit5">5</div>
    <div class="digit 6" id="digit6">6</div>
    <div class="digit 7" id="digit7">7</div>
    <div class="digit 8" id="digit8">8</div>
    <div class="digit 9" id="digit9">9</div>
    <div class="digit +" id="digitPlus">+</div>
    <div class="digit 0" id="digit0">0</div>
    <div class="digit -" id="digitMinus">-</div>
    <div class="digit * star" id="digitMultiply">*</div>
    <div class="digit /" id="digitDivision">/</div>
    <div class="digit =" id="digitEquals">=</div>
    <div class="digit clear" id="clearBtn">C</div>
    <div class="digit ac" id="resetBtn">AC</div>
    <div class="digit . decimal" id="decimalBtn">.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is very impressive!

To fix your issue you're going to want to limit the number of characters that can be added to `displayCurrentResult`. Now you're going to need to figure out what exactly you're wanting to do when `displayCurrentResult` reaches the limit, but this is how I would do it.

```
if (
    (displayCurrentResult.substring(-1) === "*" ||
      displayCurrentResult.substring(-1) === "/" ||
      displayCurrentResult.substring(-1) === "-" ||
      displayCurrentResult.substring(-1) === "+") &&
    (inputValue === "*" ||
      inputValue === "/" ||
      inputValue === "-" ||
      inputValue === "+")
  ) {
    displayCurrentResult = displayCurrentResult.slice(0, -1) + inputValue;
  } else if(displayCurrentResult.length >= 8) {
     // Action after limit is reached would go here
    return;
  }else {
    displayCurrentResult += inputValue;
  }
  display.innerText = commaSeparator(displayCurrentResult);
}
```

You would just add the code to complete whatever action you're wanting to complete in that `else if()` where nothing is returned. I would either stop number input 1 before what I did so you can add your operators.